# Sharepoint 2016 search result issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

I configured SharePoint 2016 Enterprise Search and everything work good my crawling has not any error and crawl all files my main issue is in the search result some files if I do not write it in full name I can not get result ex: I have EXCEL file named as 001610458996 I want that if I wrote middle numbers get me the result or just first 5 numbers I put star also but still not getting any result but if I write it in full number like 001610458996 then I can see that file its same for all other files also if a file name include any symbol I have to write  \   before that symbol then I can get the result how to fix that to give my any result I type 
Regards,

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is the normal behaviour of SharePoint. If you look at the [Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference) you'll notice that only prefix-matching is supported, suffix-matching is not.

In your case: searching for `001*` should work (if the name is part of the fulltext-index) whereas `*996` will never work.

Comment: thanks so much for your answer so there is no way to make my search find files even it was written half of it and it never return back files name which is include symbols

Comment: Actually the issue is that even in advance search I can not search as I want I wrote just 4 middle number in advance search and still have same issue

Comment: There is no difference in search, when in advance mode. Only the UI is different. The same restrictions still apply: Suffix-matching is still not supported.

Comment: Thanks Nils for your reply so there is no any way to get in result what I want brings what you time even half name of file

Comment: No. Only if you search from the beginning (i.e. "001*")

Comment: actually that work and dear what about files name that include symbols I have to put \  before the symbol then I can get it how to fix that please